# Detect dead code in C#

Tags: c#, detection, dead-code

How can I detect dead code in my C# application?

Comment: Do you use Resharper? )

Comment: Follow the smells.

Comment: @The_Smallest:I d'nt use Resharper

Comment: There is smell everywhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile your code and check the warnings in the Error List. The following code:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
        return null;  // unreachable
    }
```

produces this warning:

```
Warning 11  Unreachable code detected   <fullpath>\HomeController.cs    13  13  <prjname>
```

Tools like JetBrains ReSharper (http://jetbrains.com/resharper)* can also perform this analysis on the fly and highlight dead code.

* ReSharper is a commercial tool.

Comment: You can set Visual Studio to treat warnings as errors. Project Properties... Build... Treat warnings as errors... Specific warnings: 0162. Then any dead code will result in a compiler error, which you can easily browse to. (I'm assuming that you consider VS free and/or C# Express supports this. I haven't checked.) I don't know of a free VS add-in that will highlight dead code.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 and the Microsoft C# compiler reliably highlight unreachable code within methods. They ignore unused private methods though.

Answer (score 9):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can handle that. You could also check out [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

If you don't feel like paying for either of those, I believe you can analyze your project with FxCop and it will also identify dead code.

Answer (score 2):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) identifies dead code and unused parameters/locals and so does [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=917023F6-D5B7-41BB-BBC0-411A7D66CF3C).

Answer (score 0):

Mind that these tools do not detect the dead code in the comments.
For example, the following:

```
// var a = 123;
// DoSomething(a);
```

will not be detected as dead code.

As of July 2020, I could not find any code inspection tool that could detect dead code in the comments. Therefore I developed one on my own (based on Roslyn) and published it under MIT license:
https://github.com/mristin/dead-csharp.